# How to have multiple methods with InlinKeyBoardMarkup - telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to have 2 methods with quick replies. These 2 methods are cmd_language and cmd_crypto. The problem is that the first method (cmd_language) works well, but the second method doesn't.

I want the program works like this:
I type /start, "Welcome" is typed, then cmd_language is executed automatically showing "Select the language" and the options (for now that works). Then I type /crypto, the options is showed but when i select an option i get an error.

```
from telegram.ext import *
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

#-------------------- START ------------------------
def cmd_start(update, context:CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text("Welcome")
    cmd_language(update, context)
    
        
#-------------------LANGUAGE---------------------------
def cmd_language(update, context:CallbackContext):
        
    languages= [[InlineKeyboardButton("Español", callback_data="ES")],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("English", callback_data="EN")]]
    
    menuLanguages = InlineKeyboardMarkup(languages)
    
    update.message.reply_text("Select the language", reply_markup=menuLanguages)
        
def selectionLanguage(update, context):
    
    query = update.callback_query
    
    language = query.data
    query.edit_message_text(text=f"You have selected {language}")
    
#-----------------------CRYTO-------------------
def cmd_crypto(update, context:CallbackContext):
        
    cryptos= [[InlineKeyboardButton("ADA - Cardano", callback_data="ADA")],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("BTC - Bitcoin", callback_data="BTC")]]
    
    menuCryptos= InlineKeyboardMarkup(cryptos)
    
    update.message.reply_text("Select the cryptocurrency:", reply_markup=menuCryptos)
        

def selectionCrypto(update, context):
    
    query = update.callback_query
    
    crypto= query.data
        
    query.edit_message_text(text=f"You have selected {crypto}"))

#----------------ERROR-------------------------
def error(update, context):
    print(f"Update {update} caused error {context.error}")

#--------------MAIN-------------------------------
def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", cmd_start))
    
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("language", cmd_language))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(selectionLanguage))
    
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("crypto", cmd_crypto))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(selectionCrypto))    
    
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial part here is the line "Order and priority counts" in the docs of [`Dispatcher.add_handler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_handler): Your first `CallbackQueryHandler` will just handle *any* incoming `CallbackQuery` and the second one will never be fired.

As solutions to the problem, I propose to either:

- use the `pattern` argument of [`CallbackQueryHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html) or
- use a [`ConversationHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) to fetch user input in a multiple-step setup.

Please have a look at the [`inlinekeyboard2.py`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#inlinekeyboard2py) example, which showcases both.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not exactly what i want. Can I make that /cmd_language and /cmd_crypto works independently?, i mean that i could type /language and the options be showed and i could type /crypto and the options be showed as well

Comment: Sure, that works - even if you use `ConversationHandler` for both