# python-telegram-bot to retrieve user-authored messages from telegram

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)


async def isim(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULTTYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.replytext('Lütfen eklemek istediğiniz ismi giriniz', replymarkup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    return linkekle


async def isim_ekle(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    user = update.message.text
    print(user)
    await update.message.reply_text('isminiz: '+ user)


def main():
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN").build()
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("Start", hello))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("isim", isim))
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, isim_ekle))
    app.run_polling()

if __name == '__main':
    main()
```

Friends merahaba. I'm trying to make a python bot, I'm stuck somewhere, the user will write `/name`, the bot will tell him to enter the name, we will enter the name and print our name on the screen, the code at the top does this, but if I write what I want, it prints it on the screen, what I want is to write `/name`, it will only print the answer I give. but the bot writes the same thing no matter what I write to the group without writing the `/name` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have multiple methods with InlinKeyBoardMarkup - telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719451/how-to-have-multiple-methods-with-inlinkeyboardmarkup-telegram-bot)